# Wordpress dreaded white screen while creating or updating a post

Tags: wordpress, screen

I created a wordpress theme and after uploading and activating the scheme to the server everything looks all right... but when I try to use the admin section of wordpress then I am having a problem with a 'white screen' or when creating new posts and when trying to log out... when i try to update a post or create a new page it just stays on post.php and the page is left blank.. Please suggest what should i do? 
I have the same theme running on my local xampp server but it working ok.

Comment: I think i solved the problem..! I just removed every blank line and php end tag from functions.php of my theme..  and that worked!

Comment: What was the problem? (you can write an answer and self-accept it)

Comment: I think the problem was in the functions.php file of my theme.. i just removed any space from top or bottom of the file and the php end tag. The admin section is working properly now. :)
Maybe this post would be useful to someone else..

Comment: I had a similar problem where anytime I added or updated a post I got the white screen. The problem for me was also in the functions.php file. Not sure what it was specifically, but I put I went back and got an older version. Problem solved for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enbale **Debug** in your wp-config file , there must be an error in the code which is causing this issue.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Comment: The wp-config.php file is in the root of your wordpress install.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where anytime I added or updated a post I got the white screen. The problem for me was also in the functions.php file. Not sure what it was specifically, but I went back and got an older version of the file. Problem solved.